# Missing MetaData In WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, web-config

I am running into an issue where my WCF REST service does not seem to have metadata.   This prevents me from using the WCF Test Client.

The rest of the service appears to build and generate the service definitions correctly.   Here is my web.config.   What am I missing here?   Any constructive input would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
        <clear />
        <add name="Requests" connectionString="REMOVED" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="Requests.Requests" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Requests.IRequests" bindingConfiguration="WebBinding" behaviorConfiguration="EndpointBehavior" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WebBinding">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="EndpointBehavior">
                    <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF REST services doesn't use metadata, it's available for SOAP only. Try to use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or other similar tool as a test client

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem - having never used WCF Test tool before I was completely stumped.

I found the following answer from Carlos Figueira very insightful:

> This is a limitation of the web programming model itself. Unlike SOAP
>   endpoints (i.e., those with BasicHttpBinding, WSHttpBinding, etc)
>   which have a way to expose metadata about itself (WSDL or Mex) with
>   information about all the operations / parameters in the endpoint,
>   there's currently no standard way to expose metadata for a non-SOAP
>   endpoint - and that's exactly what the webHttpBinding-based endpoints
>   are. In short, the WCF Test Client won't be useful for web-based
>   endpoints. If some standard for representing web-style endpoints
>   emerges when WCF ships its next version, we'll likely update the test
>   client to support it, but for now there's none widely adopted.

Read more at [WCF Test Client and WebHttpBinding](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/deabd25b-a219-4e95-9826-d40dc2f75543/wcf-test-client-and-webhttpbinding?forum=wcf)